# How to analyse audio that comes in via HTML5 input?

Tags: html5-audio

How could I analyse the pitch that comes in via HTML5 audio input (for example Chrome can do this)? I'm talking about a user singing into his mikrophone and the application analyses the pitch level to tell him what note he sings (or how close he is to hitting that note).

[Pocket Full Of HTML5](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/pocket_full_of_html5/) seems to be able to nicely analyse audio but it doesn't use live input.

Do you have any tips for me?